# Getting "command not found" error message when running "git log" on Windows

Tags: windows, git, git-log

I have installed git and all the commands work properly except `git log`. When I type `git log`, this message appears:

```
command not found
```

what could be the possible reason for such a strange behaviour?

---

```
$ git --version
git version 2.16.1.windows.4

$ which git
/mingx64/bin/git
```

Comment: Just to complete the question, can you mention your `git --version`?

Comment: What do you on  running command `which git` ?

Comment: @RomainValeri the outcome of "git --version": git version 2.16.1.windows.4

Comment: @Anmol the outcome of "which git": /mingx64/bin/git

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution and wanted to share it with those who may come across the same error. It seems `git log` uses PAGER to show the messages and what I did was to use the `git config --global core.pager ''` command to stop git from using PAGER.

Comment: Having a broken `$PAGER` will break other things too; probably better to set it to something useful. If you don't have either `more` or `less`, you can set `PAGER=cat` to have it work without actually being useful.

Comment: ... Oh, you're on Windows? Maybe try setting it to `type` if you don't even have `cat` (but seriously think about getting rid of Windows. You can thank me later).

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue (or something similar to it).

Check inside your git config file, which you can find by running `git config --list --show-origin`

Check to see if you have any properties appended to that file that look incorrect.

For my issue, I had:

```
[core]
fsmonitor ==
```

Which was incorrectly setting a git property to an inappropriate value, causing the output to be: `=: =: command not found`